# Continuously extending a function $X\in C^{3,\alpha}(B_1(0),\mathbb{R}^3), B_1(0)\subset \mathbb{R}^2,$ to $\overline{B_1(0)}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry

Let $$B_1(0):= \{w\in \mathbb{R}^2 :\lvert w\rvert < 1\}$$ be the unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is it true that a function $$X\in C^{3,\alpha}(B_1(0),\mathbb{R}^3), \alpha\in (0,1),$$ can be continuously extended to $\overline{B_1(0)}$? What about the partial derivatives?

Comment: In the future, edit your question rather than deleting and reposting it. That is considered bad form here. Thank you.

Comment: The closed ball is a complete metric space and the open ball is dense in it. If third partial derivatives of $f$ are **globally** Hölder of exponent $\alpha$, they are uniformly continuous on the open ball: they extend as uniformly continuous function on the closed ball. Hence, second partial derivatives are Lipschitz, and uniformly continuous. Repeating the above show that $f$ and all its partial derivatives up to order $3$ extend (uniformly-)continuously on the closed ball.